# Qual è il significato di "svasarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Il mio letto consisteva in un divano del solito velluto rosso con basi d'appoggio lucide, in cui si specchiava tutto ciò che pensavo. Il solo mobile era un tavolino nero senza un grano di polvere, con un vaso esile che non **si svasava** come tutti i vasi, in alto. Nel vaso non c'era niente, nemmeno un fiore rosso. Qualche libro nasceva sul tavolo quando lo desideravo.

Si tratta di fantasticherie dell'io narrante sulla stanza da letto che avrebbe voluto avere.

Malgrado abbia cercato il verbo "svasare" in parecchi dizionari, non riesco a capire il suo significato nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puoi trovare il significato in [svasatura](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svasatura/):

> d. Nelle lavorazioni, in genere, leggera conicità che si conferisce a
> un pezzo, metallico o di altro materiale, per facilitarne l’estrazione
> dalla sede (avente anch’essa una corrispondente svasatura) o per
> agevolarne il forzamento in essa. Anche, l’angolo di apertura delle
> teste o delle punte dei chiodi fresati.

Nel caso del vaso la svasatura è l'apertura a forma conica del collo che facilita l'inserimento dei fiori.

In figura un esempio:

[image]

Nel passaggio da te citato il vaso descritto sembra avere un collo esile come una bottiglia, a differenza dei normali vasi per fiori.